# vgetq_lane_u64(x, 0) versus vget_low_u64(x)

Tags: c, arm, neon, intrinsics

ARM instrinsics include functions to extract scalars of different sizes. The functions are documented most completely in the [ARM® C Language Extensions](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ihi0053b/IHI0053B_arm_c_language_extensions_2013.pdf):

> ```
> ET vgetQ_lane_ST(T vec, const int lane);
> ```
>
> gets the value from the specified lane of an input vector. There are
>   24 intrinsics.

And:

> ```
> T vget_high_ST(T2 a);
> T vget_low_ST(T2 a);
> ```
>
> gets the high, or low, half of a 128-bit vector. There are 24
>   intrinsics.

I know an equivalence exists in some circumstances. For example, on a little-endian machine, the following holds true for 64-bit values:

```
uint64x2_t x = ...;
vgetq_lane_u64(x, 0) == vget_low_u64(x);
```

A similar equivalence exists for the high lane:

```
uint64x2_t x = ...;
vgetq_lane_u64(x, 1) == vget_high_u64(x);
```

My question is, what are the practical differences since both functions return a scalar? Should one be preferred over the other?

Comment: `on a little-endian machine` is probably not relevant, since at no point are you indexing an array.  Indexing elements in a vector register is more like left/right shifts of an integer in a scalar register.  I haven't looked, but I assume that architectures that can run in either endianness don't change the behaviour of instructions that shuffle vectors, or insert / extract a scalar into / out of a vector.  (Of course, if the scalar comes from memory, endianness matters for the order of bytes within the scalar, but not the element position within the vector.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd consider the overlap an implementation detail. "...since both functions return a scalar" isn't even true, for starters: `vgetq_lane_u64()` returns a `uint64_t`, which is a scalar; `vget_low_u64()` returns a `uint64x1_t`, which is a unit-length vector. Consider that this guy also exists:

```
uint64_t vget_lane_u64(uint64x1_t v, const int lane)
```

Semantically, use `vget_{high,low}` wherever you have a Q register output from a vector operation, and need to split it to pass the data into further vector operations on D registers. Use `vget{,q}_lane` when you are actually extracting a single value to pass off to scalar code. I'm pretty sure that implicit conversion between unit-length vector types and scalar types isn't actually guaranteed anywhere, so I certainly wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: *""...since both functions return a scalar" isn't even true..."* - Oh, you're right; I missed that detail. It seems GCC and Clang are mostly accommodating because they convert between the `uint64_t` and `uint64x1_t` without warning.

Comment: @jww Beware [the GCC vector extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Vector-Extensions.html#Vector-Extensions) ([similarly for Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#vectors-and-extended-vectors)) - you can get away with an awful lot of dodgy stuff with NEON types thanks to those.

Comment: Thanks. That's really neat syntax; its very natural. I don't believe we use the extensions - we tend to be fairly vigorous about only using portable intrinsics. But that page partially explains a GCC 4.9 bug when `-std=c++11` is used: [Where is __v2di declared when using -std=c++11 under GCC?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38051959)

Comment: When using intrinsics (and purely intrinsics) the code is portable regardless of endian-ness. For that to work you need to construct vectors using the vld<n> or vcreate/vcombine intrinsics. You must steer clear of the GCC Vector extension syntax for vector initialisation (`uint64x2_t vec = { 1, 2 }; // Not endian-safe`) and always initialise an array, then load it (`uint64_t a[2] = { 1, 2 }; uint64x2_t vec = vld1q_u64 (a); // endian-safe). The details as to how and why this is the case but the LLVM compiler documents some of the reasoning in http://llvm.org/docs/BigEndianNEON.html

Comment: And I'm back to this because of a Microsoft ARM64 port. Everything I thought I had straightened out has changed... Microsoft's ACLE declares are very different: [`arm64_neon.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/km/crt/arm64_neon.h).